# Image strategy on Android

Tags: android, json, strategy

I am creating an application with lots of photos. They will take `> 100 mb` on memory. So far I have 3 ideas:

> 1. Place it in `@drawable`  - app will be heavy
> 2. Download by JSON and place in java array - caching - How long it can be there?
> 3. Download by JSON, place it on phone memory/SD card and read in the application from memory. User can Remove pictures.

The best option will be to give possibility to user if he want to have a pictures or not.

What strategy is most efficient and recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 or 3 seems to be the best solutions for this situation.

Option 2 `Download by JSON and place in java array` is not recommended since it's not reliable. 
The OS might kill your application process when it's in the background therefore destroying the memory cached images.
This would require users to redownload the 100mb of images all over again next time they open your app (not a good idea on mobile).

Option 1 `Place it in @drawable` might lead to a larger intial app download, but at least guarantees the images are present and will never require a re-download. Also, since you're not downloading anything in the background, your users will know how much space the application will take on their device from the get-go.

Option 3 `Download by JSON, place it on phone memory/SD card and read in application from memory.`  allows for a smaller app download. And caching images on the SD-card instead of memory would bypass the issues option 2 has. Libraries like [android-query](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) have this kind of functionality available with only 1 or 2 lines of code. (See [Image Loading](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) docs)

If your app can't function properly without the images (crashes, bugs, glitches etc.), the images won't be updated in the future and you don't mind large app packages, go with option 1.
Else, go with option 3.